# How to resize image in folder using php?

Tags: php, resize

How to resize image in folder using php ?

i try to use this code to resize image `$imgPath ="test_images/english-728b1414843000.png";` to `200x200 px`, but not work, how can i do that ?

```
<?php
    function resize($width, $height, $imgPath, $nm){
        /* Get original image x y*/
        list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES[$nm]['tmp_name']);
        /* calculate new image size with ratio */
        $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
        $h = ceil($height / $ratio);
        $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
        $w = ceil($width / $ratio);
        /* new file name */
        $path = $imgPath;
        /* read binary data from image file */
        $imgString = file_get_contents($_FILES[$nm]['tmp_name']);
        /* create image from string */
        $image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        //$nm = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 300);
              imagealphablending( $tmp, FALSE );
              imagesavealpha( $tmp, TRUE );
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,
        0, 0,
        $x, 0,
        $width, $height,
        $w, $h);
        /* Save image */
        switch ($_FILES[$nm]['type']) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
                imagejpeg($tmp, $path, 100);
                break;
            case 'image/png':
                imagepng($tmp, $path, 0);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                imagegif($tmp, $path);
                break;
            default:
                exit;
                break;
        }
        return $path;
        /* cleanup memory */
        imagedestroy($image);
        imagedestroy($tmp);
    }
?>



<?PHP
    $imgPath ="test_images/english-728b1414843000.png";
        $valid_exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
        // thumbnail sizes
        $sizes = array(200 => 200);
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES[$nm]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts)) {
            /* resize image */
            foreach ($sizes as $w => $h) {
                $files[] = resize($w, $h, $imgPath ,$nm);
            }

        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . '/thumbs/');
while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
        // echo '<img style="margin:10px;" src="pictures/' . $file . '" border="0" />';
        $ter = 'thumbs/' . $file;
        $image = strtolower($ter);
        $extname = getExtension($image);
        if ($extname == "jpg" || $extname == "jpeg") {
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($ter);
        } else if ($extname == "png") {
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($ter);
        } else {
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($ter);
        }
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($ter);
        $newwidth = 120;
        $newheight = 140;
        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
        $filepath = $file;
        $filename = 'thumbs/' . $filepath;
        imagejpeg($tmp, $filename, 100);
        imagedestroy($src);
        imagedestroy($tmp);
    }
}

function getExtension($str) {
    $i = strrpos($str, ".");
    if (!$i) {
        return "";
    }
    $l = strlen($str) - $i;
    $ext = substr($str, $i + 1, $l);
    return $ext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please add code on htacess

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^p/(\d+)x(\d+)/(.*).(jpg|png)$ image.php?url=$3&ext=$4&height=$2&width=$1 [L,QSA]

create image.php and put this code--
<?php
include('smart_resize_image.function.php');

$newheight = (int) $_GET['height'];
$newwidth = (int) $_GET['width'];
$image = $_GET['url'];
$ext = $_GET['ext'];
$path = "{$image}.{$ext}";

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$resizedFile = "p/{$newwidth}x{$newheight}/{$image}.{$ext}";

mkdir(dirname($resizedFile), 0755, true); 

$path = trimAndGet($path); //remove white/gray background around image

smart_resize_image($path, null, $newwidth, $newheight, true, $resizedFile, false, false, 90);

and use smart resize library
```